# $And operator on Mongoldb full text research with word stemming

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

Our project is built on mongodb and I'm doing a full text search with a $and operator on words.

I've searched for similarly questions for this problem ([MongoDB Text Search AND multiple search words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902674/mongodb-text-search-and-multiple-search-words)), but the solution of surrounding words with quotation marks would take out Word Stemming, which is the whole interest of using full text search.

For example, this code with not find "Items that want to be found":

```
find({$text:{$search:"\"Item\"",$language:"en"}})
```

Does anyone can provide a solution to this WITH Word Stemming?