# Search any word in string mongodb with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, search, advanced-search

I want to create advanced search in project that is in Node JS with Mongo DB. I have created a field in DB that is search-key. user can type any word in text box and i want to match in this word in string and fetch the result. below my db structure and code. my code work only match first word of string not search in all string.

```
DB : 
{
"_id": ObjectId("001"),
 "searchkey": "Test Product Test Product T-shirt Half sleeves Adidas"
} 
{
"_id": ObjectId("123"), 
 "searchkey": "boy test Product Test Product T-shirt Half sleeves Nike"
} 
{
"_id": ObjectId("456"), 
 "searchkey": "girl test Product Summer Product T-shirt full sleeves Adidas"
} 
{
"_id": ObjectId("789"), 
 "searchkey": "any product any Product any Product T-shirt full sleeves Adidas"
} 
{
"_id": ObjectId("1010"), 
 "searchkey": "woodland Product woodland Product T-shirt Half sleeves woodland"
} 
{
"_id": ObjectId("1212"), 
 "searchkey": "Summer Product Test Product T-shirt Half sleeves Adidas"
} 

My Query : 

Collection.find({searchkey : {$regex: new RegExp('^' + search.toLowerCase(), 'i')},searchkey : {$regex: new RegExp('^' + search.toUpperCase(), 'i')},is_active:true},function(error,fetchSearch){
console.log(fetchSearch);
});
```

If i search `test or TEST` it will give me only one result that id is 001 and rest of the result not match from all string.

I want like if i search `summer` or `Summer` that it will give me `456 and 1212` _Id data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only checking if the string is starting with the user's search string.

`^` = means start of string, so `'^' + search.toLowerCase()`  means search for a string which is starting with `search.toLowerCase()`, and that's it. If it wont start with the search string - it wont match. That's why for `test` only id 001 get a match.

Change your search pattern to: `'.*' + search.toLowerCase() + '.*'` to find the search string anywhere inside the strings.

[Here is the new regex](https://regex101.com/r/jLYKkT/1), you can see it is matching 'Summer' with both 456 and 1212

Comment: it means now my query like below

Comment: Collection.find({searchkey : {$regex: new RegExp('.*' + search.toLowerCase()+'.*', 'i')},searchkey : {$regex: new RegExp('.*' + search.toUpperCase()+'.*','i')},is_active:true},function(error,fetchSearch){
console.log(fetchSearch);
});

Answer (score 3):

Change your query like this:

```
db.getCollection('Stackoverflow').find({ searchkey: {$regex: "test", $options: "$i"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Already answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/50693553/6517383. Here is a simple function I made to search using subwords in node. Hope it helps someone

Let's suppose a user search for `pri nks` so it should satisfy printer and inks but $text search doesn't allow for this so here is my simple function:

```
    var makeTextFilter = (text) => {
    var wordSplited = text.split(/\s+/);
    /** Regex generation for words */
    var regToMatch = new RegExp(wordSplited.join("|"), 'gi');
    let filter = [];
    searchFieldArray.map((item,i) => {
        filter.push({}); 
        filter[i][item] = {
            $regex: regToMatch,
            $options: 'i'
        }
    })

    return filter;
  }
```

and use it in your query like this

```
let query = {...query, $or: makeTextFilter(textInputFromUser)}
tableName.find(query, function (err, cargo_list)
```

Comment: thanks for reply but this issue is resolved. this question i was asking couple of years.  :)

Comment: Mahajan sahb it is for other users they might find it helpful

Comment: Ok Mahajan sahb, you are also mahajan? You are from.

Comment: Yes, Amritsar Punjab