# MongoDB Text Search AND multiple search words with word stemming

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I am trying to search for multiple words in text inclusively(AND operation)
without losing word stemming.

For example:

db.supplies.runCommand("text", {search:"printers inks"})
should return results with (printer and ink) or (printers ink) or (printers ink) or (printers inks) , instead of all results with either printer or ink.

This post covers the search for multiple words as an AND operation, but the solution doesn't search for stemmed words ->[MongoDB Text Search AND multiple search words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902674/mongodb-text-search-and-multiple-search-words).

The only way I could think of is creating a permutation of all the words and then running the search for the number of permutations(which could be large)

This may not be an effective way to search on a large collection.

Is there a better and smarter way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

So is there a reason you have to use a text search?  If it were me i would use a regular expression.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Off the top of my head something like this.

```
db.collection.find({products:/printers inks|printers|inks/})
```

Now i suppose you can do the same thing with a text search too.

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search : "\"printers inks\" printers inks"}})
```

note the escaped quotes.

Comment: The OP wants all terms to exist in each matched document.  Both of your answers are too permissive, they match documents with only one of the terms.